# PhoneGap redirect From server html file to local file

Tags: android, cordova

I am in the process of developing an iPhone PhoneGap application and have stumbled into a problem redirecting the user after login.

The flow is as follows:

1. Application is loading.
2. I am redirecting the user to a login page which is located on a remote server and passing a parameter of the current page so the user will be redirected after a successful login.

   e.g. http://www.myloginserver.co.il?ret='this is the url of the local html file'.

The problem is I cant get the login page to redirect back to the local html.

i have tried passing the following urls:

1. window.location.href
2. window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("www/")
3. "file:////" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("www/")

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I'm not sure if it is possible...what I would do instead is create the login form locally in your /www/ and use AJAX to query the server and see if they were able to login. Then in the callback function of your AJAX request you can determine if you can send them to the next page or if they need to retry the login.

Comment: This is exactly what I have planned as my fallback solution :) I am trying to figure if there is another solution.